# Effects of nested unionMoveSelectors in optaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

During testing and benchmarking, I unintentionally introduced an additional level of `unionMoveSelector` in my xml solver configuration file:

```
<unionMoveSelector>
    <unionMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <fixedProbabilityWeight>1.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
                    <valueSelector variableName="start"/>
                </changeMoveSelector>
                <changeMoveSelector>
                    <fixedProbabilityWeight>1.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
                    <valueSelector variableName="duration"/>
                </changeMoveSelector>
                <swapMoveSelector>
                    <filterClass>io.solvice.shift.domain.ShiftAssignmentSwapFilter</filterClass>
                    <fixedProbabilityWeight>0.1</fixedProbabilityWeight>
                </swapMoveSelector>
                <swapMoveSelector>
                    <filterClass>io.solvice.shift.domain.EmployeeSwapFilter</filterClass>
                    <fixedProbabilityWeight>0.1</fixedProbabilityWeight>
                </swapMoveSelector>
                <moveIteratorFactory>
                    <fixedProbabilityWeight>0.1</fixedProbabilityWeight>
                    <moveIteratorFactoryClass>customMoveIteratorFactory1</moveIteratorFactoryClass>
                </moveIteratorFactory>
                <moveIteratorFactory>
                    <fixedProbabilityWeight>1.0</fixedProbabilityWeight>
                    <moveIteratorFactoryClass>customMoveIteratorFactory2</moveIteratorFactoryClass>
                </moveIteratorFactory>
    </unionMoveSelector>
</unionMoveSelector>
```

Extensive testing (albeit on a single, hard-to-tackle instance) has shown that my solver performs better **with** this additional level than without.

Can someone please explain to me what this does and why it might outperform the other situation?